# Pie chart presentation and estimates of packets

Tags: statistics

Three sacks have packets of sugar:
Large:$250$ packets
Medium: $210$ packets
Small: $225$ packets

If mass of large packet is $1.5$ times that in a medium packet and $2.5$ times that in a small packet.
Present the above information on a pie chart as angles, for masses of arge, medium and small sacks
and estimate the number of packets sold if the were on sale.

Comment: Anyone to help me understand this question. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If we take the mass of a large packet as $1$, the mass of a medium is $\frac 1{1.5}$ and the mass of a small is $\frac 1{2.5}$.  Multiply these by the number of each type of packet to get the total mass of each type.  The angle of the large packs should be $\frac{mass of large packs}{mass of all the packs} \times 360^\circ$.  There is no information to "
estimate the number of packets sold if the were on sale.